# How to Update and combine dictionaries without looping?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

```
x = { "123456" : {2017-04-16': {'2298': 'yes','578' : 'no'}} }
y = { "123456" : {2017-04-16': {'38': 'yes'}}}
expected_output = {"123456" : {'2017-04-16': {'2298': 'yes','38' :'yes','578' : 'no'}}}
```

How to do above operation efficiently??
I have to perform 100M+ such operation for 1000's of feilds

I tried navigating into dictionary and combining them, but it takes time which is not acceptable

Comment: Maybe this can be useful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-in-python-taking-union-o

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to merge the dictionaries together:

For Python versions 3.5 or newer, you can execute:

```
x = { "123456" : {'2017-04-16': {'2298': 'yes','578' : 'no'}} }
y = { "123456" : {'2017-04-16': {'38': 'yes'}}}

newDict = {**x, **y}
```

For Python versions 3.9 or newer, you can also execute:

```
newDict = x | y
```

instead of `newDict = {**x, **y}`

Comment: new Dict will be  newDict = {'123456': {'2017-04-16': {'38': 'yes'}}} 
I need expected_output = {"123456" : {'2017-04-16': {'2298': 'yes','38' :'yes','578' : 'no'}}}